# My load and "Finished in" times when running RSpec are varying. Can I speed them up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Right now, most of my tests run against Models.  Currently I have about 100 tests. When running them all I see:

Finished in 3.99 seconds (files took 17.97 seconds to load)
Finished in 3.93 seconds (files took 17.51 seconds to load)
Finished in 2.03 seconds (files took 2.36 seconds to load)  <<< Now that seems better
Finished in 4.27 seconds (files took 17.45 seconds to load)
Finished in 1.98 seconds (files took 2.4 seconds to load)  <<< Now that seems better

The total 20 second delay seems like a lot to me and I am seeing it randomly.  Is this something I should accept, or might there be a better way?  As the number of tests grows, I am concerned my development cycle will become cumbersome.  I know I can run individual or groups of spec files.  I'd like to optimize running the whole set, if possible.

Not sure what items to add, but here are a few:

- RSpec v3.0.4
- Spring version 1.1.3
- Rails 4.1.5
- Mac OS X 10.9.4

spring status reports:
..$ spring status
Spring is running:

17524 spring server | app_name | started 137 hours ago
22503 spring app    | app_name | started 77 hours ago | development mode

Comment: Did you try [`parallel_tests`](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests)?

Comment: No.  The biggest penalty seems to be "load time."  parallel_tests looks like it will address processing time. Will parallel_tests (productively) affect load times?

Answer (score 2):

First of all - make sure you are running your spec suite with spring:

```
spring rspec
```

That will ensure that the environment is preloaded by spring and that RSpec uses the preloaded environment.

If you haven't already setup spring with rspec, just add `spring-commands-rspec` to your Gemfile:

```
gem "spring-commands-rspec", group: :development
```

Then stop spring so that it picks up the new config:

```
spring stop
```

One you are doing that, do not trust the load times being reported by RSpec. The load time numbers you are seeing are probably wildly inaccurate. When running RSpec with spring, the load time seems to refer to when spring was first started:

```
> time spring rspec

Finished in 9.12 seconds (files took 1 minute 11.36 seconds to load)
345 examples, 0 failures

spring rspec  0.45s user 0.06s system 4% cpu 10.304 total
```

As you can see, RSpec reported that it took 1 minute 11.36 seconds to load, but in actuality the entire suite loaded and ran in 10.3 seconds!

If I run the test again 2 minutes later:

```
> time spring rspec 

Finished in 9.01 seconds (files took 3 minutes 18.5 seconds to load)
345 examples, 0 failures

spring rspec  0.44s user 0.06s system 4% cpu 10.209 total
```

**Update**

There is an open issue for the inaccurately reported load times:

https://github.com/jonleighton/spring-commands-rspec/issues/18

There is a workaround in the issue, which is to add `Rspec.configuration.start_time = Time.now` to the binstub in `bin/rspec`. With that in place I get consistent sub 1 second load times:

```
time spring rspec

Finished in 8.46 seconds (files took 0.53673 seconds to load)
345 examples, 0 failures

spring rspec  0.46s user 0.06s system 5% cpu 9.214 total
```

Comment: I have edited my question to show the output of 'spring status'

Comment: Also, I do not think I am seeing the aberrant reporting of load time you describe.  In my case, the load times seem about right to me.

Comment: Thanks.  That would be a reliable way to mark the time.  Sill, when the set of tests load and process in 4-5 seconds, it seems like 4-5 seconds to me.  When the load+process time is reported as ~20 seconds, that too seems about right.

Comment: I added a link to the offical bug report for the inaccurate load time reporting under spring

Comment: OK, but the total time sems about right for me.  Honestly, I do not know how much is loading and how much is processing, but the sum looks correct to me.

Comment: If you are using spring the load time should be negligible.  That's the whole point of using spring. If the load time is actually several seconds you have a problem with your configuration.